# Node access permission but show view teasers and search result teasers

Tags: 7, users, search

I use [Content Access module](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access) and [Profile 2 module](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) to restrict access to specific nodes and assign a specific role during registration.

The problem now is that the search results are not visible? How do i manage after you search, the teaser results are visible, but you can't go to the full content of the specific node? Do i have to use other module or another method?